# How to include child objects in nativequery list?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In this simplified example, I have code that returns a list via a native query

```
String query = "SELECT id, first_name, last_name, email FROM person";
List<Person> personList = session.createNativeQuery(query).list();
```

Now we have added an address object that allows multiple addresses per person  (no address key has been added to the person table since it is a one to many relationship)

```
  class Address {
    private Integer personId
    private String streetAddress;
  }
```

We want the address list object to be included in the result set for each person record

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the entity type being returned - Person.class

```
String query = "SELECT p.*, a.* FROM person p, address a WHERE p.id = a.person_id";
List<Person> personList = session.createNativeQuery(query, Person.class).list();
```